# Why so much difference?

Tags: r, optimization

I am wondering, why there is so much difference between fitdistr and manually optim?

my code:

```
data<-c(1:1000)
fitdistr(data, "t")

logfunction <-function(par){
if(par[2]>0 & par[3]>0) return(-sum(log(dt((data-par[1])/par[2],df=par[3])/par[2])))
else return(Inf)
}

optim(c(0,0.1,2.5),logfunction)
```

Output of fitdistr:

```
     m            s            df    
  500.500000   288.355653   366.450581 
 (  9.143496) (  6.468072) (285.589770)
```

Output of opitm:

```
[1] 499.5142 292.9602 304.5050
```

Why is there so much differencein the second and third parameter?

Answer (score 1):

The call made by `fitdistr` is equivalent to

```
optim(c(median(x), IQR(x)/2, 10), logfunction, method="BFGS")
```

It gives you a different answer because you are starting from a different point and using a different algorithm (your call uses Nelder-Mead, the default for `optim`.)